# MySql - How to get the latest movie from each director

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table (movies) where i need to find the latest movie directed by each director.....

[image]

this query seems to get me the result of it:

```
SELECT title 
FROM movies 
WHERE year IN (
    SELECT MAX(year) 
    FROM movies 
    GROUP BY director
);
```

But I can't figure why "La La Land" by Steven McQueen ... Which is not supposed to be on the output

[image]

Comment: You got exactly what you asked for. Your query looks for movies that were released the same year as the latest movie of any director.

Comment: la la land in 2010?

Comment: I mean... "Bee Movie" and "Deadpool" must only be there for Steven McQueen because those are the latest movies directed by him.

Comment: Unless the movies are ranked with some other column other than year, you will have to declare a tie breaker for directors with movies in the same year. You could say same year by MAX(id) if id indicates order in which a movie was released, in which case the significance of the year field would be reduced..

Comment: So I guess this only query will do for this table... TT                                              
                                                                                                    SELECT title FROM movies WHERE title IN ("Deadpool","Bee Movie",Monster Inc.","Finding Nemo","Begin Again","Up","Boss Baby","Moana","Frozen");

Comment: thx sir Ross Bush

Answer (score 0):

You need a correlated sub-query.

If multiple movies were released by a director in the most recent year, all of them will be included.

```
 SELECT m1.title
 FROM movies m1
 WHERE m1.year =
       (SELECT MAX(m2.year)  
        FROM movies m2
        WHERE m1.director=m2.director)
```

Comment: @Xboss - If you post your data in text form (not as an image) I will show you the working sample of my code.